# How to present second child viewController in Landscape view ( parent -> child -> child(Landscape)) nested child

Tags: ios, swift3, landscape

I am trying to force only one viewController in landscape, need to be in landscape view [Parent -> child -> child in landscape view].

Below are my code:

from parent viewController presenting first viewController (first child)

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: ControllerStoryboardName.player.description) as! FirstViewController
self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Then from First viewController presenting second viewController (second child)

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: ControllerStoryboardName.player.description) as! SecondViewController
self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

The second viewController which i need to show in landscape mode. Below are my second viewController override methods for force landscape:

```
override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
        return true
}

override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask{
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.landscape
}
```

My appDelegate method:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        if self.window?.rootViewController?.presentedViewController is SecondViewController {
            return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.all
        }else{
            return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait
        }
    }
```

From Parent to single child is in landscape mode is working fine, but when i tried from parent to child and then child in landscape mode is not woking. The second child is presenting in portrait mode need to be in landscape mode. How to achieve this?.
Any help would be Appreciated.